# No realizar la sumatoria el ciclo FOR

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

Estoy realizando Punto de Venta, y esta función la utilizo para agregar los items a la grilla y que me plantee al final el total en un entry. Al momento de realizar la suma solo pone el valor del total de las filas que fueron agregadas pero no realizar la suma de las filas que fueron agregadas.La grilla tiene los campos 'id', 'producto', 'cantidad', 'precio' y 'precio total', justamente la sumatoria que quiero realizar es el precio total de cada uno de los items que agrego a la grilla, pone el valor que existe en la columna 'precio total' que tienen los productos insertados por Ej: el producto vale 25, se inserta correctamente luego añado otro producto que vale 10 y en vez de insertarse 35 en el entry se inserta '102510'.

```
def agregar_item(self):

    cantidad = self.cantidad_prod.get()
    precio = self.precioU.get()
    menuP = self.menu_productos.get()
    menuPID = self.menu_productosID.get()
    total = IntVar()
    total = precio * cantidad
    suma_total = 0

    # Evalua si los campos estan vacios o rellenos.

    if cantidad != 0 and precio != 0 and menuP != '' and menuPID != '' :
        pass
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title = 'ERROR', message = 'Para continuar, necesita completar los campos')
        return

    # Insertar datos

    self.grilla_productos.insert('', 0, text = menuPID, values = (menuP, cantidad, precio ,total))
    self.cantidad_prod.set('')
    self.precioU.set('')
    self.menu_productos.set('')
    self.menu_productosID.set('')

    # Suma total

    for item in self.grilla_productos.get_children():
        registro = int(self.grilla_productos.set(item, "#4"))
        suma_total =+ registro
        print(suma_total)
        self.suma.insert(0, suma_total)
```

Comment: No logro entender el cuerpo de la pregunta. Podrías explicarme a que te refieres con "no realizar la suma de ambas"? O mejor aun, replantea el cuerpo de la pregunta para que sea más claro.

Comment: Ya esta!, disculpame, pensé que me expresé bien.

Comment: Gracias! No pasa nada c: Ahora te quería pedir otra cosa. Por lo que entiendo el bucle for no te realiza la sumatoria. Que es lo que hace? No modifica el entry? Si es eso, tengo una sospecha. Pero para confirmar, podrías hacer de tu código un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) por favor?

Comment: Exacto, pone el valor que existe en la columna 'precio total' que tienen los productos insertados por Ej: el producto vale 25, se inserta correctamente luego añado otro producto que vale 10 y en vez de insertarse 35 en el entry se  inserta '102510'. Creo que ahí explique bien el problema porque no me genera un error python sino sucede eso.

Comment: Podrías agregar esa aclaración en la pregunta para mejorarla por favor? En breve te doy una respuesta.

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

El método insert de los Entrys, tal como dice su nombre, se encarga de **insertar** texto. No borra en ningún momento.

En cada item del treeview que recorres, añades nuevo texto al principio del Entry. Ese texto representaría el valor de total en cada registro.

Por ejemplo tienes los totales 10 y 25

- En la primera inserción, funcionaría bien, hay un solo total y se inserta 10.
- En la segunda inserción, el entry tiene el valor 10, te agrega al principio el primer total que aparece en el treeview (25) y luego el segundo total (10), quedandote 102510.

#### Un pequeño error extra

Además, tienes un error en esta linea:

```
suma_total =+ registro
```

No es =+, es +=

```
suma_total += registro
```

#### Solución

Establece el valor del entry solo una vez (o sea no lo establescas dentro del bucle for), usando el método delete para borrar el valor previo.

```
# Suma total

for item in self.grilla_productos.get_children():
    registro = int(self.grilla_productos.set(item, "#4"))
    suma_total += registro
    print(suma_total)

self.suma.delete(0, "end")
self.suma.insert(0, suma_total)
```